# Edit Array Outside its Bounds

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have an Array with Defualt "Cat", "Dog, "Simon", "Smith"
the length is therefore 3.

If I want to edit smith I type array[3] = "JR Smith"

but if user want to add another thing to the array I tried: array[4] = "Car"
But it gave me out of bounds.

How do I extend an array outside it's initialization?

//Simon

EDIT*

Ye I know there is List. But isnt there a way with array. becuase it took me ages to write like 200 length array...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not extend an array outside its initialization. For such a purpose use of an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is advised. It has the property to grow beyond its predefined size.

A simple example of using ArrayList can be found [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=234)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a list. Arrays are not dynamic in java :

```
 import java.util.*;

 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 list.add( "cat" ); 
 list.add( "dog" ); 
 list.add( "bird" ); 
 //later
 list.add( "car" );
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using ArrayList. You can always convert the ArrayList to an array using the toArray() method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29

Answer (score 1):

There is kind of a way to enlarge an array:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] newArray = new int[5];
System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, 0, array.length);
array = newArray;
array[4] = 5;
```

`array` is now `{ 1, 2, 3, 0, 5 }`

You create a bigger one, copy the old one into the new one and use the new one. That's also what `ArrayList` does internally.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ArrayList` instead. Once you initialize an array you cant change its size, unless of course you re-initialize it.

See here [Java dynamic array sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647260/java-dynamic-array-sizes)

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite way is to import java.util.Arrays and then use something along the lines of:

```
List tempList = Arrays.asList(yourArray)
tempList.add(whateverYouWant)
yourArray = tempList.toArray();
```

First line converts your array to a List, second adds to the list, and the third changes it back.