# How to auto increment the size of an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, auto-increment

How the array size is auto increment in java program my requirement is "create a 2 dimensional array 
sno, in the first dimension
name, age in the second dimension
so if  i pass sds, 25
it should be added to the array [0][sds,25]
the array should keep incrementing"
my code is like this:

```
void values() throws IOException{for ( int row = i; row < len; row++ ){
            for ( int column = 1; column <= 1; column++ ){
                arrayValues[row][0] = String.valueOf(row+1);
                System.out.print("Enter "+(row+1)+" Name: ");
                String name = br.readLine();
                System.out.print("Enter "+(row+1)+" age: ");
                int age = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                arrayValues[row][column]= name+","+age;
            }
void incrementSize() throws IOException{String[][] newArray = new String[arrayValues.length][];
    System.out.println(newArray.length);
String[][] t = Arrays.copyOf(arrayValues, newArray.length);
```

After this how can done my code Please help me

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a different data structure. Have a look at arraylist.

Comment: No boss is said to me implement this way only

Comment: May be he is testing you that weather you are aware of arraylist or not :)

Answer (score 4):

I think the perfect bet of your requirement is   [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

> Resizable-array implementation of the List interface.

Comment: Sorry i don't want use ArrayList

Comment: bcoz my boss is said to me implement this way only since it is assignment give me any suggestion

Comment: If you want to use arrays for resizable arrays you'll end up recreating what arraylist does "under the hood" anyway (probably less efficiently). I really would check you boss doesnt want arraylists

Comment: P.s. why are you throwing away all the object orientated nature and going with a 2D array rather than a 1D array of Person objects (each with a name and age field). As you're doing it now you're holding age in a String, that makes me very sad

Comment: Yeah,It is like using steps ,when you have lift :).

Comment: May be your boss is testing you that weather you are aware of arraylist or not :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) for this requirement. You can use a `ArrayList<ArrayList>` in place of 2-dim array. [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is *Resizable-array implementation of the List interface.*

*An array is a container object that holds a **fixed number of values** of a single type.*

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new array in order to make the size bigger, there is no dynamic way to increase an existing array.

Here is a way you can create a new array to increase the size.

```
int[] a = new int[5];
// fill a
int[] b = Arrays.copyOf(a, 10);
```

Comment: for single is ok, but how is 2-D and if i can do this way that shows null pointer wxception

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking a dynamically growing data structure. you can use implementation of list interface which is in java collection frame work. you can use ArrayList or Vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Using `java.util.Arrays` class it is possible. Please refer below link for answer.

[How to increase string array size automatically or dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37748185/1624035)