# Continuous input gathering until conditions met?

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to understand gathering user input and looping until conditions.
I want to loop a scanner until user inputs 0, however, I need each inputted integer to be stored so it can be accessed for later use. The hard part is, I can't use an array.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Is this in Java? Also if you can't use an array...what can you use?

Comment: Yes, this is Java sorry

Comment: Are you allowed to use `List` if you can't use arrays?

Comment: The prof. didn't go over lists, so I doubt it.

Comment: Well, arrays and lists are basic data structures for storing things. I can't think of anything else where you can store for future usages.

Comment: use a string and your own seperator. Troll the condition of not using arrays

Comment: How would I go about doing this if I used an array?

Comment: Since you don't know the number of elements in user input, you can't use simple `Array` because to initialize arrays, you need to know the initial size. Easiest approach would be to use `ArrayList` which uses `Array` in it's backend. Refer to my answer.

Comment: Use an ArrayList, Stack, Queue, or Set. See my answer below, you have many options.

Answer (score 0):

simply you can do something like

```
List mylist = new ArrayList(); //in java. other wise you can create array[size]
int input = 1;
while(input!=0)
{
  /* input number from user here */

  if(input!=0)
  mylist.add(input);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to loop user input until `0` is entered.

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean loop = true;
String input;
while(loop) {
    input = console.nextLine();
    //Add input to a data structure
    if (input.equals("0")) {
        loop = false;
    }
}
```

As far as adding the user input to a data structure, you said you can't use an Array. How about a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) or a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). Even a [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) or a [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) would work. Have you looked at using any of these data structures?

Here is a basic example using a List:

```
List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
aList.add(input);
```

And this is how you might use a Stack:

```
Stack<String> stk = new Stack<String>();
stk.push(input);
```

Perhaps the most efficient way would be to use a HashSet:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.add(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays here would be little tricky since you don't know the numbe of elements user is going to enter. You can always write the code to create a new array with bigger capacity once user has exhaused initial capacity and copy over existing input elements but using `List` would be much easier.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<Integer> input = new ArrayList<>();
    int nextInt = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    while((nextInt = scanner.nextInt()) != 0){
        input.add(nextInt);
    }
```

See this question if you really want to use arrays. Answer explains on creating new arrays and copying over elements. [Java dynamic array sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647260/java-dynamic-array-sizes)