# How to increase the size of an array in sub class

Tags: java

In sub class, is it possible to increase the size of array that is declared public in super class.
Could you please give me an example.

Comment: Note that the size of an array is not "declared".  It's determined at the time that the variable is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are by design fixed length. The length of an array is established when the array is created. After creation, its length is fixed **You can't change size dinamically** what you can do is *reallocate* the array (creating a new instance of it maximizing the size (for example *2)) , but if you do that, you have to copy all the content of the previous array. 
If you want to use a dynamic structure take a look to [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) that already handle reallocation of the array etc.

Answer (score 0):

If it's set as protected or public, than yes: A subclass will be able to edit it's parents fields.

Comment: Yes it is public in super class.

Comment: Not all arrays are fixed. Either way, you could easily copy the contents and redefine the length by creating a new array then assigning those copied objects.

Comment: @Buzzyboy Yes, [array lengths are fixed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2).

Comment: int[] array = new int[5];
array = new int[6];
ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
I could go on.

Answer (score 0):

You Should just use a dynamic array:

[Dynamic array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647260/java-dynamic-array-sizes)

since all arrays are of fixed-length that once defined cannot be resized.

Comment: Or replace the array with a larger one and copy the contents.

Comment: that is another option, but dynamic arrays are nicer :)

Comment: All a dynamic array is is a fixed-size array that does the swap automatically.

Comment: True, but there are a few different ways to create a dynamic array in Java

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't create a "true" dynamic array in Java, only an array or array-like object (like `ArrayList`) that behaves like a dynamic arrays. Arrays in Java are [defined to have a fixed length](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use ArrayList than Array with fixed size.

```
  ArrayList<String> ar =new ArrayList<String>();
  ar.add("Value");
```

Answer (score 0):

In below program SuperArrayClass contain the arr which get be dynamically change in the subArrayClass .in case if you provide the less than the previous size ,in that case it will throw Exception

```
class SuperArrayClass {
    public int arr[];
    private int size;

    SuperArrayClass(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        arr = new int[size];
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;

    }
}

class SubArrayClass extends SuperArrayClass {

    SubArrayClass(int size) {
        super(size);
    }

    /**
     * @param size
     *            :provide the new size of the array
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public void changeSizeTo(int size) throws Exception {

        if (getSize()<  size) {
            int temp[] = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                temp[i] = arr[i];
            }
            arr = temp;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Size provided is less than previous size");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happen if new size is not greater as previous size?