# Not sure about Array size

Tags: java

How may I define an array in Java. when I am not sure of the Arrays size.
I am doing it to avoid Null Pointers

```
int[] arr1 = new int[21];
int[] arr1 = {11,22,33};
```

These are of fixed length, i need to declare an Array where the items to be stored in it will be decided at run time?

Comment: Have the size be a variable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647260/java-dynamic-array-sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Array lists are created with an initial size. When this size is exceeded, the collection is automatically enlarged. When objects are removed, the array may be shrunk."

[ArrayList Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `ArrayList`, which dynamically grows/shrinks according to how many elements you place/remove in it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 1):

if you are not sure just declare it like this:

```
int[] arr1;
```

but you must know its size when you initialise it later:

```
arr1 = int[20];
//or
arr1 = {1, 2, 3};
```

On the other hand this is the situation where you should use `List` (like `ArrayList`) since they resize dynamically.

EDIT:

```
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
 //adding 
 list.add(2);
```

more methods here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: I think he means initialising an array without knowing the size. But yeah you are right.

Comment: Yes, seems right. I have never used ArrayList, reading about it. Can you give me the best way to declare/initialise it?

Comment: see my edit (I explained how to use it)

Comment: Very Nice! worked it today. went off very well