# Arrays and user input in Java

Tags: java, arrays

So for arrays I'm trying to ask the user to input 10 numbers between 1 and 100 into an array. I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around this. I do not understand how to set an array size AND have it call from a variable associated with user input at the same time. Is it even possible to do this? I'm not asking for a solution but maybe just a better way to understand this. My school book does not help much.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Even I don't understand how it is possible unless you tell us the programming language in which it is supposed to be done.

Comment: java, sorry I'll add that do the main post.

Comment: Check this link if you are getting input count from user and need dynamic array -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647260/java-dynamic-array-sizes

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
int pos = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (pos < 10) {
    System.out.print("input a number(1-100):");
    int a = in.nextInt();
    if (a > 0 && a <= 100) arr[pos++] = a;
}
```

And don't forget to `import java.util.Scanner;`

Comment: `ask the user to input 10 numbers` - why the array and loop of 100?

Comment: ew while true forever

Comment: @neito It does not need to be like that if you use an ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide more information with your question. What language you are using? How is your program structure?

Since you already know your array size and everything it is very easy to start.

Firstly declare your array. Since i don't know what language you are using, i will just explain in c++ and java.

### C++ Example

```
int array_numbers[10]; // Which is 0-9.
```

Then you go ahead and prompt the user for an input.

```
cout << "Please enter 10 numbers : ";
```

Once this is done, the user is now going to input 10 numbers. For this you do a loop with the command to store the values.

```
for(int x=0;x<=9;x++) //
{
       cin >> array_numbers[x]; //entering the input into the variable index x
}
```

finally to display the value:

```
for(int x=0;x<=9;x++)
{
     cout << "array_numbers[" << x+1 << "] is : " << array_numbers[x]; 
     //x+1 to show the index to the user.
}
```

---

### Java Example

and another example in java

Declaring the variable and the scanner :

```
int[] array_numbers = new int[10];
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
//import java.util.Scanner; <- don't forget to do this in the beginning
```

Then the loop :

```
for(int x=0;x<=9;x++)
{
    array_numbers[x] = scan.nextInt();
}
```

and lastly to display the results:

```
for(int y=0; y<=9; y++)
{
    System.out.println("array_numbers["+ (y+1) +"] is : "+ array_numbers[y]);
}
```

---

Please do comment on this if you need further help.