# Lucene how to add a Term to a Term[]

Tags: java, lucene

I have this sample (just a snip where the MultiPhraseQuery is built):

```
// *** MultiPhraseQuery ***
    MultiPhraseQuery mQuery = new MultiPhraseQuery();

    // *** TermL1 ***
    mQuery.add(new Term[] {
                    new Term("abstract", "quick"),
                    new Term("abstract", "fast")
                    });

    // *** TermL2 ***
    Term t1 = new Term("abstract", "fox");
    Term t2 = new Term("abstract", "rabbit");

    Term[] termL2 = new Term[] {
            t1, t2
            };
    mQuery.add(termL2);
```

I'd like to build TermL2 with an iterative method (like a loop) to allow to add a dynamic number of terms (t1, t2, t..., tn). It doesn't seem to be such an hard problem but I haven't any found a solution since a while now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java dynamic array sizes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647260/java-dynamic-array-sizes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n;
//Set this variable to the # of terms
String nextTerm;
Term[] termL2 = new Term[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    nextTerm = blahblah; //here you set your next term
    termL2[i] = new Term("abstract", nextTerm);
}
mQuery.add(termL2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot: exactly what I've been looking for!