# How can I create an array(s) that only add to the list if a condition is met

Tags: java

How can I create an `array`s that tracks student names and their corresponding credits, but only adds the student information(i.e. name + credits) to the `array` if only a certain condition is met?

Comment: What can *this* be for??? Who would use an old plain Java array for such a purpose? Consider using `List` instead!

Answer (score 4):

You can extend `Arraylist` and override the `add()` method:

```
public class ConditionalArrayList extends ArrayList<Object> {
  @Override
  public boolean add(Object e) {
    if (condition)
        return super.add(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible without using ArrayLists?

Comment: possible, but more complex because of the resizes, you cannot add dynamically objects to an array, but you can use `Arrays.asList()` easily to convert them

Answer (score 0):

```
class RecordOfStudent{
    String[] record_value;
    if((name!=null))&&(credit!=null)){
        String record=name+credit;
        record_value={record};
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an object, here I called it StudentRecord, that contains the information on the name and credit, the following would work in your main:

```
StudentRecord records = new StudentRecord[numStudents]; //numstudents set ahead of time
if(condition){  //such as (currRecord.credits == 90) 
    records[count] = currRecord;  //currRecord is the record you are testing
}
```

This would work, but you would have to constantly reallocate the array if you didn't know your size in advance. ArrayLists really would work better.

If you must use arrays, however, this question will help:
[Java dynamic array sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647260/java-dynamic-array-sizes)