# How to increasing Array sizes , add a new Array slot at the end of the array?

Tags: java, arrays

i am building a program like a Shop that have products and have the options of sell them with price and everything .. i wanted to make a options that will allow me to add new Products to the array from the program the its self for doing that i need to increase my array length . and i kind of stuck know , ty for all your help !!

```
Proudact MilkProd = new Proudact("Milk", 5.55, 50, 10, 0);
Proudact ChessProd = new Proudact("Chess", 4.35, 50, 10, 1);
Proudact AppleProd = new Proudact("Apple", 1.25, 50, 10, 2);
Proudact WotermelonProd = new Proudact("Wotermelon", 6.21, 50, 10, 3);

Proudact [] MyArray = {MilkProd,ChessProd,AppleProd,WotermelonProd};
NewProd(MyArray);

public static void NewProd(Proudact[] MyArray){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        MyArray[length] = MyArray[MyArray.length+1];
        System.out.println("Enter Proudact Name : ");
        String Name = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Proudact Price : ");
        int price = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Proudact Stuck : ");
        int Stuck = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Proudact MinStuck");
        int minStuck = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Proudact Id :");
        int id = scan.nextInt();
        Proudact NewProudact = new Proudact(Name,price,Stuck,minStuck, id);
        MyArray[MyArray.length]=NewProudact;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java dynamic array sizes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647260/java-dynamic-array-sizes)

Comment: Use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Arrays have a fixed size, a static length.  You cannot increase or decrease their size.  You should use an `ArrayList` instead.  Arrays are useful but are nothing compared to OOP solutions.

Comment: Any problem with the usage of ArrayList?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use a list instead of array because Arrays have static lengths but lists have dynamic.

So instead of:

```
Proudact[] MyArray = ...
```

Create new list of type Proudact like this:

```
List<Proudact> myList = new ArrayList<Proudact>();
```

And then you can simply add items to list like this:

```
myList.add(new Proudact(Name,price,Stuck,minStuck, id));
```

So the full example for your case should look something like this:

```
List<Proudact> myList = new ArrayList<Proudact>();

myList.add(new Proudact("Milk", 5.55, 50, 10, 0));
myList.add(new Proudact("Chess", 4.35, 50, 10, 1));
myList.add(new Proudact("Apple", 1.25, 50, 10, 2));
myList.add(new Proudact("Wotermelon", 6.21, 50, 10, 3));

public static void NewProd(Proudact[] MyArray){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter Proudact Name : ");
        String Name = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Proudact Price : ");
        int price = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Proudact Stuck : ");
        int Stuck = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Proudact MinStuck");
        int minStuck = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Proudact Id :");
        int id = scan.nextInt();
        myList.add(new Proudact(Name,price,Stuck,minStuck, id));
    }
}
```

Check java collections tutorial [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/list.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

in Java, arrays can not be dynamically enlarged.
I suggest you'll use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to create a new array of larger size and copy all data from the old array over there. But must you use an array? A [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) would be much easier to use

Answer (score 0):

Use an ArrayList and then convert it to array if that is what you want in the end.

```
List<Proudact> proudactList = new ArrayList<>();
```

populate it with objects of Proudact class & then convert it to array

```
Proudact[] array = proudactList.toArray(new Proudact[proudactList.size()]);
```