# Creating an array that counts up to a given number

Tags: java

I need help creating an array that counts up to a given number. The output should look something like this:

```
Enter a positive integer: 8
Counting up: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
Counting down: 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
The first 8 multiples of 5: 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40
The first 8 multiples of 10: 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] myList = new int[1];

    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
    promptUser(myList);

    int[] testArray = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };
    System.out.print("Test array: ");
    printArray(testArray);

    System.out.print("Counting up: ");
    int[] countingUp = countUp(n);
    printArray(countingUp);
}

public static void promptUser(int[] a){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        a[i] = input.nextInt();

    }
}

public static void printArray(int[] array){
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        System.out.print(array[i]);

    }

public static int[] countUp(int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        int count = 0;
        while(count<n){
            count++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Everything seems to work alright except for the last method called countingUp.

Thank you so much!

Comment: What array does `countUp` return?  I don't see any `return` statement at all, which means your program shouldn't compile.

Comment: Surely the compiler gives you some errors for that code?

Comment: why do you need an array myList to store a single numeric value?

Answer (score 1):

```
   public static int[] countUp(int n){
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            int count = 0;
            while(count<n){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

change this to

public static int[] countUp(int n){
        int [] temp=new int[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
         temp[i]=i+1;
        }
     return temp;
    }



System.out.print("Counting up: ");
    int[] countingUp = countUp(n);
    printArray(countingUp);

In this line change to

 int[] countingUp = countUp(n);
 for(int i=0;i<countingUp.length;i++){
   system.out.println(countingUp[i]+" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can start by extracting the *common logic* of ***counting*** by providing an initial message, the number of times to run, an initial value and an increment. Something like,

```
private static void count(String msg, int times, int init, int inc) {
    System.out.print(msg);
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        System.out.print(' ');
        System.out.print(init);
        init += inc;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

We can then implement the entirety of the requirements with something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
    System.out.flush();
    do {
        int num = scanner.nextInt();
        count("Counting up:", num, 1, 1);
        count("Counting down:", num, num, -1);
        count(String.format("The first %d multiples of 5:", num), num, 5, 5);
        count(String.format("The first %d multiples of 10:", num), num, 10, 10);
        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
        System.out.flush();
    } while (scanner.hasNextInt());
}
```

This will produce the requested output given an input of 8, and will then prompt for more input.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, If you are trying to change the Array Size Dynamically then It is **NOT POSSIBLE** in java Take a look @ [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647260/java-dynamic-array-sizes). I recommend you to use **ARRAYLIST** instead.

Although I have found below mistakes in your code. In your code I do not understand two things.

**First One:**

`System.out.print("Counting up: ");
    int[] countingUp = countUp(n);
    printArray(countingUp);`

What is the value of n? I think it is not being initialized.

**Second One:**

`public static int[] countUp(int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        int count = 0;
        while(count<n){
            count++;
        }
    }
}`

What will return this function? You have not returned anything from it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you don't need an array just follow below steps.

First create a class which handle all your calculating and counting

```
class SupportCounting {

public void countUp(int num) {
    System.out.print("Counting up : ");
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public void countDown(int num) {
    System.out.print("Counting Down : ");
    for (int i = num; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public void printMultiple(int num, int scalefactor) {
    System.out.print("First " + num + " multiples of " + scalefactor + " : ");
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        System.out.print(i * scalefactor);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}}
```

Then make use of that class in you main method

```
public class Counting {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer : ");
    int n = reader.nextInt();

    SupportCounting sc = new SupportCounting();
    sc.countUp(n);
    sc.countDown(n);
    sc.printMultiple(n, 5);
    sc.printMultiple(n, 10);
}}
```

Hope that helps