# How to initialize an array dynamically in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, foreach, syntax

I have tried to initialize an array dynamically and display the array
as result:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] c;
        String cmd="yes";
        while(cmd=="yes") {
            System.out.println("Enter value for c :");
            c=new int[] {in.nextInt()};
            System.out.println("Continue(yes/no)? :");
            cmd=in.next();
        }
        for(int k:c)
            System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

But at the for-each loop(i.e. line 12 from main()) it is showing error as "The local variable c may not have been initialized".

Comment: Initialize the c arr, `int[] c = null`, compiler doesn't know code flow will always go inside while loop

Comment: is the desired funcitonality to use this program to enter numbers into the array until you enter no at the continue stage?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct, you did not initialize your array. you would need to call `c=null;` for this to work.

However, if I understand correctly, you are trying to add numbers to an array of indefinite size, which you cannot do in Java. you should use an ArrayList.

you also used == to compare String values, which is a big no-no, I have changed it to `.equals` in my answer below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<>();
    String cmd="yes";
    while(cmd.equals("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Enter value for c :");
        c.add((Integer)in.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Continue(yes/no)? :");
        cmd=in.next();
    }
    for(Integer k:c)
        System.out.println(k);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the condition in the while-loop. Would be wise to fix that as well.

Answer (score 0):

For your actual compilation error, `c` could be not initialized if the loop is not executed. Even if you know it will (since `cmd` is equals to `"yes"`, the compiler don't go that far).

You will find answers that initialize at first the value, like [Neng Liu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50405319/4391450), but based on your logic, you can use a `do..while` loop since your logic show that you want to read at least once the `Scanner`.

```
do{
    System.out.println("Enter value for c :");
    c=new int[] {in.nextInt()};
    System.out.println("Continue(yes/no)? :");
    cmd=in.next();
}while("yes".equals(cmd)); //.equals is needed to compare `String` correctly
```

The condition in a `do..while` is checked after the block statement is executed (compare to a `while` that check the condition before). So the statement will be execute AT LEAST ONCE, so you are sure `c` will be initialized that way. And the compiler knows that too.

---

Since the title mention you want a the dynamic sized array, see [HamishD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50405385/4391450) to use a `Collection` that will grow on needs. And for a more complete post about `List`, see [Java dynamic array sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647260/java-dynamic-array-sizes?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)