# JavaFX + SQL: Add 1 new HBox with 3 ComboBoxes for each row of SQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I am working on a project and I need to add a HBox with 3 ComboBoxes for every row of a MySQL Database to a VBox.

I already tried some things but I am always getting errors. So I tried something like dynamic variable names.

```java
@FXML
    private VBox mon_routes;

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        PreparedStatement pr;
        ResultSet rs;
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM routes";

        try {
            pr = this.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pr.executeQuery();
            int n = 1;
            HBox r[] = new HBox[n];
            while (rs.next()) {
                r[n].getChildren().add(new CheckBox());
                r[n].getChildren().add(new ComboBox());
                r[n].getChildren().add(new ComboBox());
                mon_routes.getChildren().add(r[n]);
                n++;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I expected to get the VBox with 7 HBoxes as my DB has 7 rows.
But I am just getting tons of errors.

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at loginapp.LoginController.adminLogin(LoginController.java:110)
    at loginapp.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$358(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at adminapp.AdminController.initialize(AdminController.java:56)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 61 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Can you provide a summary example of your "ton of errors" -- those error messages will help in answering your question

Comment: First you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, since you're accessing an element after the end of the array. If you fix that one, the next issue you'll  face is a `NullPointerException`,since the array isn't initialized... (Assuming the resultset is non-empty.) Not sure at which question to point you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647260/java-dynamic-array-sizes

Comment: @MarkStewart I added the errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have to, you should avoid `Arrays`. I would use a `List` of `HBoxes`. Your code should look similar to the code below. Read the comments in the code.

```
VBox mon_routes = new VBox(); //You never create the VBox. This leads to a null pointer exception.

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    PreparedStatement pr;
    ResultSet rs;
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM routes";

    try {
        pr = this.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pr.executeQuery();

        List<HBox> r = new ArrayList();//Avoid Arrays. Use List instead.

        while (rs.next()) {
            HBox tempHBox = new HBox();//Create an HBox to store into the List or Array if you continue to use the Array.
            tempHBox.getChildren().add(new CheckBox(rs.getString(0)));//You never retrieve anything from the result set. <- rs.getSomething(). Add the CheckBox to the HBox
            tempHBox.getChildren().add(new CheckBox(rs.getString(1)));//You never retrieve anything from the result set. <- rs.getSomething(). Add the CheckBox to the HBox
            tempHBox.getChildren().add(new CheckBox(rs.getString(2)));//You never retrieve anything from the result set. <- rs.getSomething(). Add the CheckBox to the HBox
            r.add(tempHBox);//Add the HBox to the List
        }

        mon_routes.getChildren().addAll(r);//Add the List of HBox to the VBox.
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Working! Thank you!

Comment: Now I want to give each of those 3 Checkboxes an ID, so that all items of 1 colum have the same ID but all in row different IDs. How to do that?

Comment: Try to figure it out. If you can't, ask a new question.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

`r[]` is of size 1 adding the second hbox breaks things. you probably just want to create a `List<HBox>` instead. Best thing is probably to create a FXML for the component that you want to repeat, and a controller. create a method that initializes the values based on passing in a row. then you just create and add that custom view to the VBox  for each row.

Comment: I am not getting it. How should I do that? Could you please drop some code?