# Keep storing in array until there is input from users without knowing number of elements at first?

Tags: java, while-loop

I am creating in array without knowing the number of elements and instead of asking number of elements from the use I want to keep on storing till the user stops giving more inputs.
How to do that in java?

Comment: Either use an `ArrayList` instead of an array, or re-dimension your array (i.e. create a bigger array and copy all elements) when your array gets too small.

Comment: Take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647260/java-dynamic-array-sizes

Comment: A dynamic array is a fun thing to try sometime if you're intellectually curious and have some free time to waste.  Otherwise, yeah, just go the an `ArrayList` and don't look back.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ArrayList or HashSet (if uniqueness is required). 
Collections can grow dynamically as required.
If you need array as a type, accept user data into Arraylist (or any other collection) and then create array from collection using `toArray`

Answer (score 0):

Java has data structures that already do this for you (e.g. `ArrayList`). But if you really need to implement it yourself, then a standard method would be to store the number of elements you've currently stored separately from the capacity of the array (i.e. its length).

For example for a String array that starts at size 10 and doubles in size when it is full:

```
String[] array = new String[10];
int size = 0;

private add(String item) {
    if (size == array.length)
        array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length * 2);
    array[size++] = item;
}
```

If performance isn't important then you can expand on every element and avoid storing the size (as it's always equal to the array's length):

```
array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + 1);
array[array.length - 1] = item;
```