# How do I create an identifier for an Array of Strings without a predefined size in java?

Tags: java, identifier, arrayofstring

I am trying to figure out how do I create an identifier for an array of Strings which doesn't have a predefined set number of Strings in it?

I couldn't find a solution for this specific problem when searching on the internet thats why I'm asking here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is. Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description what you mean by "identifier for an array". If possible, show the source code you have and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647260/java-dynamic-array-sizes?

Comment: What?  Please show an example of what you are trying to accomplish.  You want an ArrayList?

Comment: The identifier is the same as identifiers for arrays which *do* have a known size.  I certainly hope you are not naming fields `arrayOfTenStrings`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create one "ArrayList" collection and store any number of "String" objects in it. And finally you could convert the  "ArrayList"  to "String[]".

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("String1");
...
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```